# Install control panel without installing Apache and MySQL

Tags: centos, control-panel

I have a VPS running CentOS and already have Apache/MySQL installed. I want to install some control panel but it seems all of them include Apache, MySQL and some other softwares that I don't really need. Is it possible for me to install a control panel without installing those softwares?

Comment: Are you sure those control panels actually install Apache and MySQL? I don't know of any that do that and they shouldn't need to. I don't think you understand exactly what they control panels are doing.

Comment: @JohnConde For example, I'm trying to install VestaCP (vestacp.com), in the installation process it says
    Following software will be installed on your system:
    - Nginx...
    - Apache...
    - MySQL...
    ...

Comment: That's more than a control panel. That's an entire platform/system. The control panel is just one facet of what they are giving you. Calling themselves a control panel is very misleading. Thank you for pointing that out that this existed.

Comment: WebMin and VirtualMin can be installed either way. The reason why control panels do this is because it is easier to configure the control panel and desired applications if there is some control over the package. With WebMin and VirtualMin, you can have any application pre-installed or not install them at all if you like. The warning I make for future users is this; sometimes it is far better to allow the control panel install the desired applications. Otherwise, you may have to go through some manual configuration though this is generally fairly easy to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [WebMin](http://www.webmin.com/) does not require Apache or MySQL. It runs using Perl and creates its own Perl web server on port 10000. You can administer Apache and MySQL with it.

By the way, you can use `yum update` and `yum search` and `yum install` as a 'command line control panel'. It can handle a lot of what you may need.